# Suma de filas en Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-10g

quiero sumar estos dos montos pero me salen dos filas diferentes porque son desiguales el monto deberia darme "2231" y una sola fila:

```
MONTO   NAC CEDULA  CODIGO SUBCODIGO FISCAL FECHA
1673,25 V   8018573 28     50        2017   11/05/17
557,75  V   8018573 28     50        2017   30/05/17
```

Este es la consulta que estoy aplicando:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(DETA_MTO_CUOTA) MONTO, DETA_NACIONALIDAD NAC, DETA_CEDULA CEDULA, DETA_CODIGO CODIGO, 
  DETA_SUB_CODIGO SUBCODIGO, DETA_AJUN_ANO_FISCAL FISCAL, DETA_FEC_CRE FECHA
  FROM SRH_DETALLE_AJUS
  WHERE DETA_AJUN_NRO = 6351
  AND DETA_TIPO_REG = 'A'
  AND DETA_SUB_CODIGO = 50
  GROUP BY DETA_NACIONALIDAD,DETA_CEDULA,DETA_CODIGO,DETA_SUB_CODIGO,DETA_AJUN_ANO_FISCAL,DETA_FEC_CRE
```

A pesar de que estoy usando `DISTINCT` o `GROUP BY` no logro sumar y tener una sola fila.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Es logico ya que las fechas son distintas. estas seguro que estas agrupando por los campos correctos?

Comment: Buenas amigo, quitar el DISTINCT me da el mismo resultado.

Comment: por eso cambie mi comentario. fijate lo que puse ahora...

Comment: Estoy agrupando a pesar de que hay columnas con datos distintos, la consulta que necesito que me arroje debe sumar A PESAR de tener filas distintas, quiero totalizar el MONTO.

Comment: el group by no funciona asi, agrupa solo datos iguales. lo que tu quieres, debes resolverlo de otra forma. tal vez tengas que comentar todo el problema y veremos como se puede arreglar.

Comment: Como harías tu para mostrar un total de 4 monto en una sola fila, teniendo en cuenta que hay filas con algún o algunos datos distintos? el DETA_AJUN_NRO es el PK y el posee 4 filas si no las agrupo.

Comment: pon un ejemplo de como quieres que salgan tus datos, asi podemos ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer un

```
SELECT SUM(MONTO)
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT (DETA_MTO_CUOTA) MONTO, DETA_NACIONALIDAD NAC, DETA_CEDULA CEDULA, DETA_CODIGO CODIGO, DETA_SUB_CODIGO SUBCODIGO, DETA_AJUN_ANO_FISCAL FISCAL, DETA_FEC_CRE FECHA
  FROM SRH_DETALLE_AJUS
  WHERE DETA_AJUN_NRO = 6351
  AND DETA_TIPO_REG = 'A'
  AND DETA_SUB_CODIGO = 50
)
```